# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP calls onCreate() instead of onResume()

Tags: android

So I have an abstract class extended through the entire app that overrides the back key to reorder Activity A to the front (With the flag).

So, it would be:

A > B > anywhere, and the back key *should* bring me back to A

I'm using the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, but it is entirely refreshing A for some reason and I don't want that.

So: Flag_activity_clear_top is reloading the onCreate() rather than onResume(). What gives?

Comment: Hope you did not call finish on Activity A when navigating to B and Activity A was there on Activity stack when you tried to navigate from B to A with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

Comment: No I did not. I am trying Bobbake4's idea now

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want the activity to just be brought to the top without restarting it set the [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) of the activity to singleTop in the manifest. You will receive a call to [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) when the activity is being brought to the top. onNewIntent is called before onResume. If you only want this behavior for the specific intent you can add the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)(in addition to FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) to the intent with the [addFlags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addFlags%28int%29) call instead of the manifest.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP it does state that you will need to set the single top flag as well. Can you post the code you are using with the clear top flag? I have used this flag quite a bit and those are the only requirements.

Comment: Ah! I got it. I had to add single top to both the manifest and the intent. Perfect thanks!

Comment: @VicVu It works for me. and I haven't add those flag to manifest. Did you add both the  FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) in the meanwhile? this is my code:    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityNeedOnTop.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    CurrentActivity.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the API docs for  [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

```
For example, consider a task consisting of the activities:
A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that
resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D 
will be finished and B receive the given Intent,
resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

**The currently running instance of activity B in the above example
will either receive the new intent you are starting here in its
onNewIntent() method, or be itself finished and restarted with the new intent.**
```

So I think your activity is itself finished and restarted.

Comment: Your issue should be resolved if you use android:launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest file for your activity A as mentioned by Bobbake4.